# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items In dropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting null error I am using database

```
//this is my view model
public class MasterViewModel
{
    public class AccountGroupViewModel
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AccountPrimaryGroup AccountPrimaryGroup { get; set; }
        public AccountGroupType AccountGroupType { get; set; }

    }

    public class NewAccountGroupViewModel
    {
        public AccountGroupViewModel AccountGroupViewModel { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AccountPrimaryGroup> AccountPrimaryGroup { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AccountGroupType> AccountGroupType { get; set; }
    }

    //this is my controller
    public class AccountGroupTypeViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class AccountPrimaryGroupViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{

    var accountPrimaryGroup = db.AccountPrimaryGroup.ToList();
    var accountGroupType= db.AccountGroupType.ToList();
    var accountGroupTypeViewModel = new NewAccountGroupViewModel
    {

        AccountGroupType=accountGroupType,
        AccountPrimaryGroup=accountPrimaryGroup

    };


    return View(accountGroupTypeViewModel);
}

// POST: AccountGroups/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(NewAccountGroupViewModel accountGroup)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var accountGroupNew = new AccountGroup
        {

            Name = accountGroup.AccountGroupViewModel.Name,
            AccountGroupType=accountGroup.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountGroupType,
            AccountPrimaryGroup=accountGroup.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountPrimaryGroup


        };
        var accountPrimaryGroup = db.AccountPrimaryGroup.ToList();
        var accountGroupType = db.AccountGroupType.ToList();

        db.AccountGroup.Add(accountGroupNew);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(accountGroup);
}

//this is my razerview
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountGroupType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountGroupType, new SelectList(Model.AccountGroupType, "Id","Name"), "Select Account Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
  </div>
```

//this is the selection of dropdown and this is where the problem is coming
      
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountPrimaryGroup, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountPrimaryGroup, new SelectList(Model.AccountPrimaryGroup,"Id","Name"), "Select Account Group", new { @class = "form-control" })

//this is the exception
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Source Error:

Line 27:         
Line 28: 
Line 29:             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountGroupType, new SelectList(Model.AccountGroupType, "Id","Name"), "Select Account Group", new { @class = "form-control" })
Line 30:         
Line 31:

Source File: C:\Users\Sujit\source\repos\MrSolution\MrSolution\Views\AccountGroup\Create.cshtml    Line: 29

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.]

Comment: What exactly is the null error you are getting? If you post the exact Error Message that will help.

Comment: //this is the exception Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items Description
Line 27: Line 28: Line 29: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccountGroupViewModel.AccountGroupType, new SelectList(Model.AccountGroupType, "Id","Name"), "Select Account Group", new { @class = "form-control" }) Line 30: Line 31: